# Is this weird function with argument in the integrand continuous? (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $I$ interval and $f \in C^\infty(I)$. If $t_0 \in I$, we know by the FTC that $F:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x)=\int_{t_0}^x f(t)dt$ is continuous. But if f depends on $x$, that is, $F(x)=\int_{t_0}^x f(x,t)dt$, can we still conclude that $F$ is continuous? It would be nice if it were because in a problem that I'm currently solving a similar situation arises. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove the following toy version of the statement:

> **Theorem.** Let $I$ be an interval and $f:I\times I\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Then, for each given base point $a \in I$,
>
> $$ F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(x, t) \, \mathrm{d}t $$
>
> is continuous in $I$.

*Proof.* Let $x_0 \in I$, and let $J$ be a compact subinterval of $I$ containing both $a$ and a neighborhood of $x_0$. Then $J \times J$ is compact and $f$ is continuous on $J \times J$. So, $f$ is bounded by some constant $M > 0$ on this square. Moreover, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $J \times J$. So, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $(x, t)$ and $(x', t')$ in $J \times J$,

$$ |x - x'| < \delta \text{ and } |t - t'| < \delta
\qquad\implies\qquad
|f(x, t) - f(x', t')| < \frac{\varepsilon}{1+|x_0 - a|}. $$

So, if $x \in J$ is  $|x - x_0| < \delta$

\begin{align*}
\left| F(x) - F(x_0) \right|
&\leq \left| \int_{x_0}^{x} f(x, t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right| + \left| \int_{a}^{x_0} (f(x, t) - f(x_0, t)) \, \mathrm{d}t \right| \\
&\leq M|x - x_0| + \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

This is enough to show that $F$ is continuous at $x_0$.

---

Of course, the above result is far from being optimal, and can be quickly generalized to more general setting.

Answer (score 1):

We can see that $F$ is even differentiable using the Leibniz rule. Informally:
$$F'(x)=\int_{t_0}^x\partial_xf(x,t)dt+f(x,x)
$$
We need to see that the left size "exists". Notice that $f$ is $C^1$ hence $\partial_xf(x,t)$ is continuous on $I^2$, and thus integrable. Therefore $F$ is differentiable and thereby continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general the statement is "false". Let $I = [0,2]$, $f: I^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $t_0 = 0$. Define

$$ f(x,t) \equiv 0, \;\; \text{if } x \in [0,1) \cup (1,2] $$
$$ f(x,t) \equiv 1, \;\; \text{if }x =1 $$

Define $F(x) \equiv \int_{t_0}^x f(x,t)dt$.
Then we have
$F(x) = 0$ for $x<1$ or $x>1$, but $F(x) = 1$ for $x=1$. Hence, in this case $F(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$. In general, for $F(x)$ to be continuous we would need some kinds of continuity along the $x$-component of $f(x,t)$.

Comment: They ask for $f$ to be continuous